# Syntax Error in Update Query Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run this query in Access DB (actually I am using MDB Viewer Plus)

```
    UPDATE a
SET a.importo = b.amount

FROM registrazionecogedettaglio a
INNER JOIN aapostepay b
ON a.annotazione = b.transactionid
WHERE a.annotazione = b.transactionid
AND a.conto = '250050'
```

I have also tried this one:

```
UPDATE registrazionecogedettaglio a 
SET a.importo = b.amount
FROM aapostepay b
JOIN
a ON a.annotazione = b.transactionid
WHERE a.annotazione = b.transactionid
AND a.conto = '250050'
```

In both cases I have simmilar syntax error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'b.amount from
>   aapostepay b join a on a.annotazione =b.transactionid'

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

For `Ms-access` move the `Inner join` before `SET` in update statement. Try this syntax.

```
UPDATE registrazionecogedettaglio a
INNER JOIN aapostepay b
ON a.annotazione = b.transactionid
SET a.importo = b.amount
WHERE a.conto = '250050'
```